# Avoid cutting lines in multiline text in overflow: hidden for fixed width/height container

Tags: css

In a container with fixed width and height and overflow hidden, an overflowing multiline text may be cut in the middle of a text line as such:

[image]

How to avoid this?

+
Additionally, the width and height of this element is set via Javascript to mimick the width and height of a flexbox element populated with dynamic content. So I do not know the width and height until page load.

+
Additionally, as the height of the element is dynamic I cannot decide in advance the number of lines that the text should occupy. So I cannot set line-height in relation to that.

I can modify line-height tho, and I can also modify font-size.

Here is a live example of the problem:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio. Tiene sus raices en una pieza cl´sica de la literatura del Latin, que data del año 45 antes de Cristo, haciendo que este adquiera mas de 2000 años de antiguedad. Richard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y al seguir leyendo distintos textos del latín, descubrió la fuente indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por Cicero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un tratado de teoría de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento. La primera linea del Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", viene de una linea en la sección 1.10.32

El trozo de texto estándar de Lorem Ipsum usado desde el año 1500 es reproducido debajo para aquellos interesados. Las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" por Cicero son también reproducidas en su forma original exacta, acompañadas por versiones en Inglés de la traducción realizada en 1914 por H. Rackham.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is adjust the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property to limit the number of lines shown. This can be calculated based off of the `height` of the element, using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). Simply divide the `height` of the element by the number of lines you wish to show:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: calc(200px / 3); /* height divided by desired number of lines */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio. Tiene sus raices en una pieza cl´sica de la literatura del Latin, que data del año 45 antes de Cristo, haciendo que este adquiera mas de 2000 años de antiguedad.
  Richard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y al seguir leyendo distintos textos del latín, descubrió
  la fuente indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por Cicero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un tratado de teoría de éticas, muy popular
  durante el Renacimiento. La primera linea del Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", viene de una linea en la sección 1.10.32 El trozo de texto estándar de Lorem Ipsum usado desde el año 1500 es reproducido debajo para aquellos interesados. Las
  secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" por Cicero son también reproducidas en su forma original exacta, acompañadas por versiones en Inglés de la traducción realizada en 1914 por H. Rackham.</div>
```

This gives a slightly larger vertical separation between the lines, but ensures that each line is shown without being cut off in any way.

Comment: Thank you, but the width and height of this element is set via javascript on page load, to mimick the width and height of a flex element. I am going to add this to my original question.

Comment: You could always inject that value into the `line-height` property with `.style.lineHeight = height / 3;` (or similar).

Comment: Actually this has the limitation of having to set manually the number of lines, which is not an option in my case. I can change font-size and line-height tho, those are not particularly fixed.

Comment: perhaps, building on your suggestion I could give a line height which is a multiple of the div height?